# Reading data from a URL and putting it into an ArrayList

Tags: java, url, arraylist

Hi. I am trying to read a text file from a dropbox URL and put the contents of the text file to the ArrayList.
I was able to read and out print the data by using openStream() method but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to put that data into an ArrayList

```
URL pList = new URL("http://url");
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
        pList.openStream()));

  String inputLine;

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(inputLine);
```

would appreciate the help ?

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(inputLine);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
String inputLine;
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    array.add(inputLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do:

- **Store multiple DropBox files in an ArrayList, where 1 item represents 1 file**

  Use a `StringBuilder` to stitch all the lines together to one string.

  ```
  List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
  files.add(readFileUsingStringBuilder(pList));

  public static String readFileUsingStringBuilder(URL url)
  {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String separator = "";
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
       String line;
       while ((line = br.readLine() != null)
       {
           sb.append(separator);
           sb.append(line);
           separator = "\n";
       }
       return sb.toString();
  }
  ```
- **Store each line of the file in a record of the ArrayList**

  ```
  String inputLine;
  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      array.add(inputLine);
  }
  ```